# iOS Swift - CoreLocation coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm building an app that uses CoreLocation to get user's coordinates. After I start updating location, I'll get the coordinates in didUpdateLocations. Probably because of gps calibration, in didUpdateLocations I get 2 or 3 different coordinates, until it stops. How can I call a function after updating locations has stopped that uses the last founded coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow `didUpdateLocations:` to be called repeatedly, as you rightly say, until either you hit some kind of timeout or your get sufficient horizontal accuracy. Then, right from `didUpdateLocations:`, tell the location manager to stop, and call the function.

Comment: Actual example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift If I wanted to do something more than print out the location, I would call my function right after the call to `        self.stopTrying()` at the very end of `didUpdateLocations:`.